# How to use router links in a list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router

For a project of mine I have created a navbar which has a profile icon. When the profile icon expands it previews four different options which are "Log in" "Register "Edit" "Admin". The issue that I have is that when I click on the links that expand, it's not always that I get redirected to the correct place. Sometimes it routes me to the clicked path, and sometimes it just stays on the current one i.e. nothing happens.

The list of links looks like this at the moment. Every router-link redirects to another .js component. I then map through them in the code furthest down. Any suggestions to how I can edit this in order to be redirected to the clicked link every time?

```
const guestSettings = [
  <Link key={'Logga in'} to="/SignIn" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }} >Logga In</Link>,
  <Link key={'Registrera'} to="/SignUp" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }} >Registrera Konto</Link>,
  <Link key={'Redigera'} to="/UserProfile" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }} >Redigera Profil</Link>,
  <Link key={'Admin'} to="/AdminHome" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }} >Admin</Link>,
];
```

```
              <Menu
                sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
                onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
              >
                {guestSettings.map((setting) => (
                  <MenuItem key={setting.key} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
```

[DropDown from the Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKqvE.png)

I haven't really been able to locate how to solve this with other things that i have tried.

Comment: Can you describe the cases where its not working?

Comment: Yes. It's basically just inconsistent. Sometimes when i for example click on "Log In" to get redirected to the Log In page, i do. And sometimes when i click on "Log In" nothing happens at all. It's like its mapping through the list of links and don't redirect me until it finds the correct path.

Comment: Is `handleCloseUserMenu` getting triggered each time?

Comment: That method in only triggered when the user clicks outside of the dropdown menu. Making it disappear/fold back up.

Comment: From the looks of it I believe it will get triggered even when the user clicks on the link. Try consoling something in that function and see when it gets triggered.

Comment: It seems we need more context. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]? If possible could you also create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that in your `handleCloseUserMenu` function, which at least gets called every time a user clicks on the item itself, you prevent the default behaviour which would be a redirect, so this would not work:

```
<div onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Prevent Default</a>
</div>
```